# Custom Field Control with TreeView with EventHandler issues

Tags: development, event-handlers, field-controls, 2007

I have got a Custom Field Control in SP2007 (inheriting BaseFieldControl) with an ASP.NET TreeView control in the ascx. This works fine with checkboxes enabled so Users can select from the tree.

But I wanted to lazy load the child nodes when they click on the plus sign using the TreeNodePopulate event which I've added in the CreateChildNodes method.

When I click on the plus sign it does do a postback into the Get method of the Value overriden property, but it never gets to the EventHandler method.

Is this a common thing with EventHandlers in Custom Field Controls?

Answer (score 3):

So it seems that if I declaratively mapped the OnTreeNodePopulate instead of adding it programmatically on CreateChildControls it hooks up correctly. Figured I'd put this up if others had the same issue.